# How I can showing the next card after clicking button and click again and show next card again to last card and submit with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend, card

[image]

[the results I expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRuG7.png)

What I want is to be able to produce something like this one ...

But why if else in the jquery that I executed doesn't work as expected as in the picture?

This in my html code

```
<div>
  <div class="card1 active">
    <p>CARD 1</p>
    <button class="btn-back">BACK</button>
    <button class="btn-next">NEXT</button>
  </div>
  <div class="card2">
    <p>CARD 2</p>
    <button class="btn-back">BACK</button>
    <button class="btn-next">NEXT</button>
  </div>
  <div class="card3">
    <p>CARD 3</p>
    <button class="btn-back">BACK</button>
    <button class="btn-next">NEXT</button>
  </div>
  <div class="card4">
    <p>CARD 4</p>
    <button class="btn-back">BACK</button>
    <button class="btn-next">NEXT</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this my css(less) code

```
div {
  padding: 10px;
  
  .card1,.card2,.card3,.card4 {
    display: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background: #777;
  }
  
  .active {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(() => {
  $(".btn-next").click(() => {
    if($(".card1 p").html() === "CARD 1") {
      $(".card2").addClass("active");
    } else if($(".card2 p").html() === "CARD 2") {
      $(".card3").addClass("active");
    } else if($(".card3 p").html() === "CARD 3") {
      $(".card4").addClass("active");
    }
  }); 
});
```

https://codepen.io/kucingompong-cp/pen/abNmBzQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is your click listener - you are using an if-else block which will only run the `if` statement for `$(".card1 p").html() === "CARD 1"` is always `true`.

You can fixed it by rearranging the `if-else` statements (put the `$(".card1 p").html() === "CARD 1"` in the `else` block; `$(".card2 p").html() === "CARD 2"` to the second `else-if` block, etc).

You can also ease the checking by just using the `active` class and the `hasClass` method of `jquery`. Instead of `$(".card1 p").html() === "CARD 1"`, you can go with `$(".card1").hasClass('active')`

Wrapping it up, rather than using if-else statements, I suggest you use another method for handling the button clicks. The following is my own implementation

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $(".btn-next")
  .click(e => $(e.target).parent().next().addClass('active')); 
});
```

```css
div {
  padding: 10px;
  
}

 .card1,.card2,.card3,.card4 {
    display: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background: #777;
 }
  
  .active {
    display: block;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="card1 active">
    <p>CARD 1</p>
    <button class="btn-back">BACK</button>
    <button class="btn-next">NEXT</button>
  </div>
  <div class="card2">
    <p>CARD 2</p>
    <button class="btn-back">BACK</button>
    <button class="btn-next">NEXT</button>
  </div>
  <div class="card3">
    <p>CARD 3</p>
    <button class="btn-back">BACK</button>
    <button class="btn-next">NEXT</button>
  </div>
  <div class="card4">
    <p>CARD 4</p>
    <button class="btn-back">BACK</button>
    <button class="btn-next">NEXT</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I utilized some jquery traversing methods which are `parent()` and `next()`.

Comment: I really suggest looking up the traversing methods of jquery. It will really help you a lot. @MuhammadManshur